# Position sticky not working when many childrens

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a code

```
<div style="position: relative"> 
        <section class="py-4 px-4">
            <h1 style="position: sticky; top: 50px">AQUI O STICKY</h1>
            <h1>VALIDANDO</h1>
            <h1>VALIDANDO</h1>
            <h1>VALIDANDO</h1>
            <h1>VALIDANDO</h1>
            <h1>VALIDANDO</h1>
            <h1>VALIDANDO</h1>
            <h1>VALIDANDO</h1>
            <h1>VALIDANDO</h1>
            <h1>VALIDANDO</h1>
        </section>
        <h1>POSITION</h1>
        <h1>POSITION</h1>
        <h1>POSITION</h1>
        <h1>POSITION</h1>
        <h1>POSITION</h1>
        <h1>POSITION</h1>
        <h1>POSITION</h1>
    </div>
```

position sticky not working at div, only section.

I have position at all screen

[image]

Comment: When leaving the section view, it loses the sticky, the sticky only goes to the bottom of the section

Comment: The position is only working directly to your father

Comment: Does **[this](https://jsfiddle.net/g5Lqe9nt/1/)** help?

Comment: The same error happens, when leaving the section view, the sticky is lost

Comment: position: fixed cannot you use position: fixed to move AQUI O STICKY to all the divs